# IIS WCF Service: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: wcf, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application, hosted on IIS. To this application I want to add a new WCF Service. Everything works fine when running the service locally, but when I deploy it to IIS I get an error: 'Could not load file or assembly ...'

The assemblies it gives an error for are defined in the Web.config file from my ASP.NET MVC application:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            List of assemblies..
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

But my WCF Service doesn't need these assemblies, so why does it want to load them? If I create a '/bin' folder where the Service.svc is located and add every assembly all works fine. But isn't there a better option for this?